# Database Merge with tables having different no. of columns

Tags: oracle, merge

Here is a scenario. 
I have around 300 tables in my database and I want to merge another database in my database. Both the databases have same tables but the datatype and no of columns vary. 
   Now how to convert data from other database to my database ?

eg.

```
db1: Table T1(col1 int,col2 char,......,col31 int)
db2: Table T1(col1 int,col2 char,......,col31 int,col32 char,col33 char )
```

Since datatype and no of column vary,I cant use 
"insert into db1.tbl 
 select * from db2.tbl ".

I dont want to create script for each and every table . Help me out !!!

Comment: And can you guarantee that the columns with the same name are of the same type?

Comment: Do you only want to merge the data from the two databases?

If so, and you happen to have a leading database (the database with the proper columns and types), you could create a generic script. This script could convert types ,strip columns that are not available or add null/default values for columns that weren't there before.

Comment: If @martin is correct and you can't guarantee that the columns have the same name, or the same order, then you _have_ to do this manually. If you can then you can create a massively over-complicated dynamic script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every morning I copy a large amount of tables from the production database into my datawarehouse. This is my "check & fix" procedure I run before each truncate + insert.

```
procedure check_and_fix_table(p_naam in varchar2)
  /**
   * check if columns have changed on PROD and create and execute the matching ALTER TABLE statement
   */
  is

    v_coltype varchar2(100);
    v_sql     varchar2(200);

    function check_column(p_column in varchar2)
    return boolean
    is
        v_dummy number;
    begin
        select 1 into v_dummy
        from   user_tab_cols tc
        where  tc.table_name = upper(p_naam)
        and    tc.column_name = p_column;

        return true;
    exception
        when no_data_found then return false;
    end;

  begin
    -- loop through all columns that are altered (if nothing altered, then nothing will happen
    for i in (select tc.column_name
              ,      tc.data_type
              ,      tc.data_length
              ,      tc.data_precision
              from   user_tab_cols@DB_LINK_TO_PRODUCTION tc
              where  tc.table_name = upper(p_naam)
              and    tc.column_name not like 'SYS_NC%' -- These columns are created by oracle for function based indexes 
              minus
              select tc.column_name
              ,      tc.data_type
              ,      tc.data_length
              ,      tc.data_precision
              from   user_tab_cols tc
              where  tc.table_name = upper(p_naam))
    loop
        -- create column type
        if i.data_type in ('CHAR','VARCHAR2') then
            v_coltype := i.data_type||'('||i.data_length||')';
        elsif i.data_type = 'NUMBER' then
            if i.data_precision is not null then
               v_coltype := i.data_type||'('||i.data_precision||')';
            else
               v_coltype := i.data_type;
            end if;
        else -- DATE, CLOB, BLOB, etc
            v_coltype := i.data_type;
        end if;

        -- check if the column is altered or added
        if check_column(i.column_name) then
            -- execute the ALTER TABLE to fix the column       
            v_sql := 'alter table '||p_naam||' modify '||i.column_name||' '||v_coltype;
        else
            -- add new column
            v_sql := 'alter table '||p_naam||' add '||i.column_name||' '||v_coltype;
        end if;
        execute immediate v_sql;

        -- logging change
        prc_log(c_procedureid, 1, p_naam||' changed. Fixed by executing: '||v_sql);
    end loop;
  exception
    when others then 
      prc_log(c_procedureid, 3, 'Error at copy_package.check_and_fix_table - '||substr(sqlerrm, 0, 1900));
  end;
```

Then in my main procedure I use it like this (where p_naam is the tablename passed as parameter to the procedure):

```
check_and_fix_table(p_naam);

-- full copy of table from PROD
execute immediate 'truncate table ' || p_naam;
execute immediate 'insert /*+append*/ into ' || p_naam || ' select * from ' || p_naam || '@DB_LINK_TO_PRODUCTION';
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Um, the OP specifically used the word merge. `truncate` will not help with merging.

Comment: So you use a merge instead of a truncate insert. That was not really the point. But I guess it wasn't what the OP was looking for apparently.